# Form Label not focusing on component's input

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form input component called `<cool-input>` that does not have a label because it should be able to be placed in an existing form. When I click the label element on the form I expect it to cause focus on the `<cool-input>` but that behavior does not happen.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <cool-input name="name" formControlName="name" ngDefaultControl></cool-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Here is the code for `<cool-input>`

```
import {Component, Input, Injectable} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'cool-input',
  template: `
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{placeHolder}}"/>
  `,
})

@Injectable()
export class coolInput {
  @Input() placeHolder:string = 'Cool Input!';
}
```

Comment: You can share the cool-input code please

Comment: Yes I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide @Input for the id of the input element of the component so that the label can communicate with it.

```
import {Component, Input, Injectable} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'cool-input',
  template: `
    <input type="text" id="{{inputID}}" placeholder="{{placeHolder}}"/>
  `,
})

@Injectable()
export class coolInput {
  @Input() placeHolder:string = 'Cool Input!';
  @Input() inputID:string = '';
}
```

In your template you would use it like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <cool-input inputID="name" formControlName="name" ngDefaultControl></cool-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is a plunker demoing the functionality:
https://plnkr.co/edit/QYI6mjGf4x6bfNyosSXK?p=preview